# Should this Babel-transpiled JS aroow function trigger browser errors?

Tags: babeljs

My dev environment is Vue + Vuex + Quasar, and I'm not using things like Babel or Webpack directly, but they are used by the build chain. I've recently upgraded the Quasar app to V2, which uses the Babel browserslist to target specific capabilities in the transpiring, and have started to see an error preventing my app from running. If I include IE 11, it works as it used to.

My source code has this Vuex getter defined (I've simplified it slightly to show the issue):

```
const isValidPage = state => (pageId = state.route.params?.page) => state.event?.pages?.[pageId]
```

The issue can be shown on the [Babel REPL](https://babel.dev/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=true&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAlhAagQwDZwCYAVkHMCmMAvDABTTJT4A0MBUVAThAJTEB8ZADnvgJIZiMClQB0jEAFcxPRsgC2EAPyieBNkU4j8o_ADd8YKCrX5logNqmBAXQBQQA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=true&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=script&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Cenv&prettier=true&targets=&version=7.11.4&externalPlugins=). That transpiled version is pretty much what I see in the browser console:

```
const isValidPage = (state) => (
  pageId = (_state$route$params = state.route.params) == null
    ? void 0
    : _state$route$params.page
) => {
  var _state$route$params, _state$event, _state$event$pages;

  return (_state$event = state.event) == null
    ? void 0
    : (_state$event$pages = _state$event.pages) == null
    ? void 0
    : _state$event$pages[pageId];
};
```

It throws (in Firefox 79) a `"ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable _state$route$params"` error. In Chrome 86, it fails at the same point with `"ReferenceError: _state$route$params is not defined"`.

Since I know little about Babel directly, I'm not 100% certain whether this code *should* execute, whether I need some additional Babel configuration, or whether it's a bug. Pasting the transpiled version into the source code does throw ESLint errors saying that `_state$route$params` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out this is a [bug](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/11166) in Babel 7. The [fix](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/11533) is on it's way.